# assignement from incompatible pointer type in C

Tags: c, sorting, struct, singly-linked-list, selection-sort

I have a linked list of a struct,
here is my struct:

```
typedef struct avion
{
    int code;
    int capacite;
    char etat[1];
    int date;
    int nvols;
} avion;

typedef struct element *list;
typedef struct element
{
    avion A;
    struct element *svt;
} element;
```

I want to sort the linked list in ascending order according to the element of the struct "capacite".
here is the code of the function tri:

```
list *tri(list *L)
{
   list *i,*j,*min;
   avion  x;
   for (i=L; (*i)->svt != NULL; i=(*i)->svt)
   {
      min=i;
      for (j=(*i)->svt; j != NULL; j=(*j)->svt)
      {
        if ((*j)->A.capacite < (*min)->A.capacite)
           min=j;
      }
       if (min != i)
      {
       x=(*min)->A;
       (*min)->A = (*i)->A;
       (*i)->A = x;
    }
}
return(L);
}
```

But i have the warning: assignement from incompatible pointer (in the two lines of the for loop: and i dont know how to fix it.

Is there any better way to sort my linked list according to this criterion?

Comment: Your `list` is a `struct element *`, a pointer. So your `list *`s are `struct element **`. Such pointers to node poinetsr can be useful in linked lists when you must update pointers, for example when you insert or delete items or when you swap them. But your code doesn't do that: It doesn't swap node, it swaps only the data. Therefore, the head doesn't change either. Use just `struct element *`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example in this for loop

```
for (i=L; (*i)->svt != NULL; i=(*i)->svt)
```

the variable `i` declared like

```
list *i
```

has the type `struct element **`. On the other hand the data member `svt` has the type `struct element *`. Thus this assignment

```
i=(*i)->svt
```

contains operands of different types and there is no implicit conversion from the type `struct element *` to the type `struct element **`.

Pay attention to that the function can invoke undefined behavior if it will be called for an empty list due to this expression

```
(*i)->svt != NULL;
```

Also this declaration of an array with one element

```
char etat[1];
```

does not make a great sense.

And introducing such an alias for a pointer like this

```
typedef struct element *list;
```

in general is not a good idea. It can only confuse readers of the code.

There is no need to pass to the function `tri` (that implements the selection sort) the pointer to the head node by reference through a pointer to it because the pointer itself is not being changed within the function.

The function can be declared and defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct avion
{
    int capacite;
} avion;

typedef struct element list;
typedef struct element
{
    avion A;
    struct element *svt;
} element;

int push_front( list **head, int capacite )
{
    element *new_element = malloc( sizeof( element ) );
    int success = new_element != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        new_element->A.capacite = capacite;
        new_element->svt = *head;
        
        *head = new_element;
    }
    
    return success;
}

void display( const list *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->svt )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->A.capacite );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

void tri( list *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->svt )
    {
        element *min = head;
        
        for ( element *current = head->svt; current != NULL; current = current->svt )
        {
            if ( current->A.capacite < min->A.capacite )
            {
                min = current;
            }
        }
        
        if ( min != head )
        {
            avion tmp = min->A;
            min->A = head->A;
            head->A = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    list *head = NULL;
    
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_front( &head, rand() % N );
    }
    
    display( head );
    
    tri( head );
    
    display( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look for example the following way.

```
7 -> 1 -> 2 -> 6 -> 0 -> 9 -> 0 -> 9 -> 6 -> 0 -> null
0 -> 0 -> 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 6 -> 6 -> 7 -> 9 -> 9 -> null
```

If to use your alias definition of the name `list` then the function can look as it is shown in this demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct avion
{
    int capacite;
} avion;

typedef struct element *list;
typedef struct element
{
    avion A;
    struct element *svt;
} element;

int push_front( list *head, int capacite )
{
    element *new_element = malloc( sizeof( element ) );
    int success = new_element != NULL;
    
    if ( success )
    {
        new_element->A.capacite = capacite;
        new_element->svt = *head;
        
        *head = new_element;
    }
    
    return success;
}

void display( list head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->svt )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", head->A.capacite );
    }
    
    puts( "null" );
}

void tri( list head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->svt )
    {
        element *min = head;
        
        for ( element *current = head->svt; current != NULL; current = current->svt )
        {
            if ( current->A.capacite < min->A.capacite )
            {
                min = current;
            }
        }
        
        if ( min != head )
        {
            avion tmp = min->A;
            min->A = head->A;
            head->A = tmp;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    list head = NULL;
    
    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        push_front( &head, rand() % N );
    }
    
    display( head );
    
    tri( head );
    
    display( head );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of this
typedef struct element *list;
When you write
list *i
i isn't a pointer on an element but a pointer on a pointer of an element